# Azure Function Detailed logging on Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a v2 Azure Function with an HTTP trigger. Occasionally, it will return a 500 with no additional information. I would like to set it to log more detailed information, including the error message and stack trace.

I have tried setting my host.json to look like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

but it has not resulted in any more detailed information when running locally.

With the built in logging settings seeming to fail me, I'm trying a top level `try/catch`, but I can't figure out how to return *both* the status code 500 *and* the exception object.

```cs
[FunctionName("Http-UploadFiles")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "uploadFiles")] HttpRequest request,
    ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(requestBody);

        var inventorySetGuid = Guid.Parse(body["inventorySetGuid"].ToString());
        var files = body["files"].Select(FileComponentUtilities.GetFile).ToList();
        var componentsAndErrors = await FileComponentUtilities.InsertSuitableComponentFiles(files, inventorySetGuid);

        return new JsonResult(componentsAndErrors, StorageFramework.Storage.SerializerSettings);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }
}
```

This code returns the status code 500, but does not return the exception object. I cannot find a suitable `IActionResult` for returning a 500 with an exception object. How can I accomplish this for this v2 Azure Function?

Answer (score 3):

You can return a `ContentResult` that allows you to set any status code, content, and content type.

```cs
return new ContentResult
{
    StatusCode = 500,
    Content = "Something went wrong"
};
```

But *do not* use this to return your stack trace! It's a security concern for your app and there are better ways... Turn on [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-social-antchu#enable-application-insights-integration) in your function app and use it to see your traces and errors.

Comment: Is there something that emulates Application Insights for running locally?

Comment: you dont need app insights locally, it will automatically go to the portal so long as it's enabled